# Replacing all characters in a regular expression match with another character?

Tags: regex, sed, posix

I'm doing analysis on a file and I want to mask some characters (while retaining their original byte count) before moving this file down the pipeline. For example, given `file.txt`:

```
Hello there Cory Klein
Have fun
Hello there Samantha Rodgers
```

Writing a regular expression to match the names and substituting them with `XXXXX` is pretty easy with `sed`:

```
$ sed -e "s/\(Hello there \).*/\1XXXXX/" file.txt
Hello there XXXXX
Have fun
Hello there XXXXX
```

But I would like to replace *each character in the name* with a `X` character, like so:

```
Hello there XXXX XXXXX
Have fun
Hello there XXXXXXXX XXXXXXX
```

How do I replace all characters matching a regular expression with another character?

Any regular POSIX tool is OK `sed`, `awk`, `perl`, etc. I'm sure I could write a simple python script to accomplish this, but I'm curious whether this is possible with regex alone, which would likely be more succinct. If so, I'd love to learn how so I could likely apply the concept in other places in the future.

Comment: With Perl, it is easy, `perl -lpe 's/Hello there\s*\K(.*)/$1=~s#\S#X#gr/ge'` ([demo](https://ideone.com/34gWnW)).

Comment: How are you defining a *name* in this case? In a regex, you would need to specify each name to match or each pattern to skip. It is not clear if you intend to do this.

Answer (score 2):

With sed you need to filter out lines that don't contain `Hello there` using an address:

```
/Hello there/{...}
```

Then replace whatever single non-whitespace character that comes after `Hello there` with one `x`:

```
s/(^.*Hello there *)?[^[:space:]]/\1x/g
```

We are leaving `Hello there` and its preceding characters intact using `\1`.

The whole command would be:

```
$ sed -r '/Hello there/{s/(^.*Hello there *)?[^[:space:]]/\1x/g}' file
Hello there xxxx xxxxx
Have fun
Hello there xxxxxxxx xxxxxxx
```

Comment: GNU sed only that, but nice solution!

Comment: @oguzismail You shouldn't change the regex. Instead go with `sed '/Hello there/s/\(^.*Hello there *\)*[^[:space:]]/\1X/g'`

Answer (score 1):

Perl supports advanced features to its set of regular expressions so this would be shorter using Perl:

```
perl -pe 's/(Hello there|\G(?!\A)) *\K\S/x/g' file
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/oH72f0/1)

RegExp breakdown:

- `(` Start of a grouping

  - `Hello there` Match `Hello there`
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!\A)` Start match from where previous match ends
- `)` End of grouping
- `[ ]*` Match any spaces
- `\K` Forget whatever is matched so far
- `\S` Match a single non-whitespace character

This continues to match all non-whitespace characters that comes after `Hello there` and replaces them with `x` using `g` flag.